Sets with partial sums are equal
I have two sequence of positive integers say $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5$ (they may be repeated) such that the multisets $$\{a_1, a_1+a_2, a_1+a_2+a_3,a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4,a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5, a_2,a_2+a_3, a_2+a_3+a_4, a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5, a_3,a_3+a_4, a_3+a_4+a_5, a_4,a_4+a_5, a_5\} =\{b_1, b_1+b_2, b_1+b_2+b_3,b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4, b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5, b_2, b_2+b_3, b_2+b_3+b_4, b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5, b_3, b_3+b_4, b_3+b_4+b_5, b_4,b_4+b_5, b_5\}.$$
This means that the multiset containing all consecutive partial sums of the 1st sequence is equal to the multiset containing all consecutive partial sums in the 2nd sequence.
From here can we say that either $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$ or $a_i=b_{6-i}$ for all $i$ ? I have tried with some particular examples and it worked. If it is true then can we generalize this ?
